# how to send notification (email, SMS, whatever) stealthy programacticly linux

Tags: linux, email, sms

I have seen many of the posts relating to sending email under linux but they do not address my particular need.

I want to implement code (C/C++) in my linux application that will send me back some kind of notification (in a stealthy way) under a certain program condition. All it needs to send me is less than 50 bytes of status data. The only thing I am guarenteed is that the box will be on a local network which will have access to the Internet via the usual gateway.

One possibility would be to send me a text to my wireless carrier like this: 
mynumber@verizon_gateway.com.  But that assumes that I have a mail client available on the linux box which is not a guarantee.  If I programmed this at the socket layer directly using SMTP I would have to manage a TCP connection which is not what I prefer to do.

Any suggestions of what would be a possible way to send me a notification from my linux app?

Thanks,

-Andres

Comment: You could use a web api like twitter or tumbler and wget to post to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For email you could use something like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com/), specifically their [WebAPI](http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API/mail.html) - this will allow you to send email with only a HTTP request.

For SMS you could use something like [Nexmo](https://www.nexmo.com/), which will allow you to send an [SMS with a HTTP request](https://www.nexmo.com/documentation/#txt).

Note that you'll have to include your API credentials in the compiled code - a potental security issue (for your credentials).

**Disclaimer:** I do a bit of developer evangelism for Nexmo.

Comment: @AndresGonzalez Glad it was helpful. Wouldn't mind an upvote as well. ;) Also, really would be interested in what you build if you use Nexmo, very interesting use case.